# Specify which overlays to take from another file

Tags: beamer, overlays, standalone

I have a picture with overlays in an external file. Sometimes I want to use all overlays from the picture, sometimes only some of the overlays.

Consider the following example, where the picture is defined using `tikz` and included via `standalone`. In the first frame I want to use all overlays from the picture. However, in the second I frame I only want to use the last two overlays, without changing the picture.

Currently the only way I know to do this is to adapt the overlays of the whole frame to meet the requirements for the overlays I want to include, as shown below. However, it would be nicer not to adapt the whole frame for this.

I found something related [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42834/specify-which-picture-variant-to-show/42967#42967) and tried to use it, by setting `\beamer@slideinframe` to `2` before including the picture. Then however, only the second overlay is shown, but not the third. Something like `\only-use-overlays<2,3>{...}` would be nice.

If possible it would be nice to select arbitrary frames, but currently I don't need that.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{standalone, filecontents, tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{pic.tex}
    \documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{standaloneframe}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node<1-> [draw] (n0) {$n_0$ }; 
    \node<2-> [draw] (n1) [right of=n0] {$n_1$ }; 
    \node<3-> [draw] (n2) [right of=n1] {$n_2$ }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{standaloneframe}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents}
% This frame has 3 overlays.
\begin{frame}
    First Slide
    \includestandalone{pic}
\end{frame}
% This frame has two overlays. 
% The first overlay contains the first item and the second overlay of the picture.
% The second overlay contains the second item and the third overlay of the picture.
\begin{frame}<2,3>
    Second Slide
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<+(1)> First item
        \item<+(1)> Second item
    \end{itemize}
    \includestandalone{pic}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both images separately on the same slide at the same time? `\only<2-3>{\begin{standalone}...\end{standalone}}` is probably not what you want

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It seems the pictures were misleading, so I reformulated the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{standalone, filecontents, tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{pic.tex}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
    \draw<1-> (0,0) -- (3,3);
    \draw<2-> (3,0) -- (0,3);
    \draw<3-> (0,1) -- (3,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{frame}
    First Slide
    \includestandalone{pic}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    Second Slide
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<+-> First item
        \item<+-> Second item
    \end{itemize}
    % Here I only want the last two overlays ff the picture
    \onslide<2,3>{
      \includestandalone{pic}
    }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From your question it is not completely clear to me, how you want the local overlay specifications to interact with the included ones. Should the "last two overlays" from the picture **[a]** appear in steps 2 and 3 on "Second Slide" (as above), or **[b]** as steps 3 and 4 (i.e., after the items), or **[c]** as steps 1 and 2 (i.e., together with the items)?

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I edited the question to remove the doubt. The MWE now shows the desired result, but uses ugly methods.

Comment: @HeinrichOdy: I think this "ugly methods" are your way to go.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the question [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42834/specify-which-picture-variant-to-show/42967#42967) was a related question. I can just use the method given there in a loop.

The example below produces the same output as the example in the question, however it is not necessary to adapt the whole frame to the overlays to be included. The optional parameter to `\includestandaloneslides` specifies from which slide on all overlays from `#2` (which is a tikz list) should be used.

Still the construction seems quite crude.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{standalone, filecontents, tikz}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{inframe}[2][1]{%
  \edef\inframe@current{\the\value{beamerpauses}}%
  \setcounter{beamerpauses}{#1}%
  \beamer@slideinframe=#2\relax
  \let\beamer@anotherslidetrue=\@empty
  \let\beamer@localanotherslidetrue=\@empty
}{%
  \setcounter{beamerpauses}{\inframe@current}%
}

\newcommand*{\includestandaloneslides}[3][0]{
    \foreach [count=\i] \slide in #2{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\n}{\i + #1}
        \only<\n>{
            \begin{inframe}{\slide}
            \includestandalone{#3}
            \end{inframe}
        }   
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{pic.tex}
    \documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{standaloneframe}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node<1-> [draw] (n0) {$n_0$ }; 
    \node<2-> [draw] (n1) [right of=n0] {$n_1$ }; 
    \node<3-> [draw] (n2) [right of=n1] {$n_2$ }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{standaloneframe}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents}
% This frame has 3 overlays.
\begin{frame}
    First Slide
    \includestandalone{pic}
\end{frame}
% This frame has two overlays. 
% The first overlay contains the first item and the second overlay of the picture.
% The second overlay contains the second item and the third overlay of the picture.
\begin{frame}
    Second Slide
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<+> First item
        \item<+> Second item
    \end{itemize}
    \includestandaloneslides{{2,3}}{pic}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```